# jquery UI Modal Dialog in asp.net usercontrol: Modal Overlay only on Div in UserControl

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui, user-controls

I have an asp.net usercontrol that contains a jQuery UI Dialog Control.

All works as expected execpt the grey tranparent overlay (to make the form modal) only appears on the hidden div below the form where the dialog is triggered from.

Is it possible to target this overlay to the parent div? or is this not the right solution.

I have tried the blockUI plugin (and removing the Dialog style to prevent its overlay showing), but although it "looks" right on screen it disables all the controls including the ones in the dialog popup.

Any ideas?

Added: Screenshot

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e0555a0ec5.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e0555a0ec5.jpg)

Comment: Ths div for the dialog is inside the user control, I changed this to be located ourtide the usercontrol, ie in page and I still get the same issue.

Comment: Another issue I can also see is that the page keeps growing in height, (the toolbar 'grabber' keeps getting smaller indicating I can scroll down more) This seems to use up resources too. If remove the .ui-widget-overlay class from css, this stops.

Comment: Just put the the dialog div as first thing in the page (just after <body>) and see what happens. Seems like there is something nesting your control. Maybe even a FRAME?

Comment: @harlev: thanks for the comment, I have 2 nested master pages, a page, then the usercontrol with the form layout (actual form tag is in the top master) which contains a usercontrol that contains the div. (if that makes sense) I get the same result if I move the usercontrol(with div) above the form layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a z-order issue. Can you post a screenshot to make it easier to understand. Also please post the high level HTML you are using on the aspx page.

Comment: ok, to solve the issue I needed to add "position:absolute; top:0px" to the .ui-widget-overlay class used by the jQuery UI Dialog. I was concentrating on the div that held the contents. Although your tips didnt give the exact answer, it certainly pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Do i remove the screenshot now? in case it gets deleted by the free hoster?